Need to get one record into multiple records without a union all with Oracle Sql
I am looking to take one record and break it apart into separate records without using UNION ALL.  The record contains multiple metrics with different datetimestamps.  When metrics have different datetime stamps then offer, make new column.  Only way I can get this to work is through a union all but there are at least 20+ metrics which can eventually bog it down due to amount of records in table.
Here is a sample of what is needed.

Sample CODE with UNION ALL:
with base as (
 select
   NOFFERED_COUNT,
   NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE,
   TABANDON_COUNT,
   case when TABANDON_EMIT_DATE > NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE THEN 
     TABANDON_EMIT_DATE else NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE end TABANDON_EMIT_DATE
 from METRIC_INTERVAL
where conversation_id = 'tk421'
)

select
  DTE,
  max(NOFFERED_COUNT)NOFFERED_COUNT,
  max(TABANDON_COUNT)TABANDON_COUNT
from
(
select 
  NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE DTE,
  NVL(NOFFERED_COUNT,0)NOFFERED_COUNT,
  0 TABANDON_COUNT
from base

union all

select 
  TABANDON_EMIT_DATE DTE,
  0 NOFFERED_COUNT,
  NVL(TABANDON_COUNT,0)TABANDON_COUNT
from base
)

where DTE is not null
group by
DTE    

Thanks for any help you can assist with !

If each "metric" can have it's own timestamp, then what is the point of making a tall table without a metric-type column? You'll have no idea what each timestamp represents.

You can probably do this using the UNPIVOT command

You can do it without UNION ALL by using UNPIVOT:
SELECT id,
       type,
       emit_date, 
       cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT  ID,
          NOFFERED_COUNT,
          NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE,
          TABANDON_COUNT,
          GREATEST(TABANDON_EMIT_DATE, NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE) AS TABANDON_EMIT_DATE
  FROM    METRIC_INTERVAL
  WHERE   conversation_id = 'tk421'
)
UNPIVOT (
  (emit_date, cnt) FOR type IN (
     (noffered_emit_date, noffered_count) AS 'NOFFERED',
     (tabandon_emit_date, tabandon_count) AS 'TABANDON'
  
  )
)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE metric_interval (
  id,
  noffered_count,
  noffered_emit_date,
  tabandon_count,
  tabandon_emit_date,
  conversation_id
) AS
SELECT 5,
       2,
       DATE '2024-08-27' + INTERVAL '14:04:10' HOUR TO SECOND,
       1,
       DATE '2024-08-27' + INTERVAL '14:06:15' HOUR TO SECOND,
       'tk421'
FROM   DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
TYPE
EMIT_DATE
CNT




5
NOFFERED
2024-08-27 14:04:10
2


5
TABANDON
2024-08-27 14:06:15
1




If you want the counts in columns for each type at the given dates then PIVOT the result:
SELECT id,
       emit_date, 
       noffered_count,
       tabandon_count
FROM   (
  SELECT  ID,
          NOFFERED_COUNT,
          NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE,
          TABANDON_COUNT,
          GREATEST(TABANDON_EMIT_DATE, NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE) AS TABANDON_EMIT_DATE
  FROM    METRIC_INTERVAL
  WHERE   conversation_id = 'tk421'
)
UNPIVOT (
  (emit_date, cnt) FOR type IN (
     (noffered_emit_date, noffered_count) AS 'NOFFERED',
     (tabandon_emit_date, tabandon_count) AS 'TABANDON'
  
  )
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(cnt) FOR type IN (
    'NOFFERED' AS noffered_count,
    'TABANDON' AS tabandon_count
  )
)

Which outputs:



ID
EMIT_DATE
NOFFERED_COUNT
TABANDON_COUNT




5
2024-08-27 14:04:10
2
null


5
2024-08-27 14:06:15
null
1



fiddle

If your input table had only one date column per row you could unpivot it but seeing as each row contains a separate date and count per metric your only option is to use a union, I'd suggest something like this:

with base as ( 
    select 'noffered' as type
            , noffered_emit_date as dte
            , noffered_count   as count_col
            , conversation_id
    from metric_interval

    union all

    select 'tabandon' as type
            case when tabandon_emit_date > noffered_emit_date 
                then tabandon_emit_date 
                else noffered_emit_date 
            end
            , tabandon_count
            , conversation_id
    from metric_interval

    union all --.... union the rest of your metrics

)

, cte_vertical as (
    select conversation_id, dte, type, max(count_col) count_col
    from base
    group by conversation_id, dte, type
)

-- you can just `select * from cte_vertical` here
-- but if you want each type of count displayed against a dte on one row:

select *
from cte_vertical
pivot max(count_col) for type in (
     [noffered]
    ,[tabandon]
    --... list all metric types
)
where conversation_id = 'tk421'

If you really don't want to write the unions then its possible to automate this using dynamic SQL to write the above query for you by selecting the column names from the metadata of the table. But this can be difficult to debug and maintain so I'd only suggest that if the number of metrics you're dealing with is liable to change frequently.

Thanks, I'm going to look into this and get back.

You could try to solve it using recursive cte. It is one union all, though, but then you could handle as many metrics as you have using Case expressions:
--    S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl (ID Number(6), 
                  NOFFERED_COUNT Number(3), NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE Date,
                  TABANDON_COUNT Number(3), TABANDON_EMIT_DATE Date,
                  OTHER_COUNT Number(3), OTHER_EMIT_DATE Date);
Insert Into tbl 
Select 5, 
       1, To_Date('2024-08-27 14:04:10', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
       1, To_Date('2024-08-27 14:06:15', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
       1, To_Date('2024-08-27 14:23:45', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
From Dual;

WITH    --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E :
  grid (PASS, ID, 
        NOFFERED_COUNT, NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE, 
        TABANDON_COUNT, TABANDON_EMIT_DATE,
        OTHER_COUNT, OTHER_EMIT_DATE) 
  AS
    ( Select    1 as PASS, ID, 
                NOFFERED_COUNT, NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE, 
                TABANDON_COUNT, TABANDON_EMIT_DATE, 
                OTHER_COUNT, OTHER_EMIT_DATE
      From      tbl
    UNION ALL
      Select    PASS + 1, ID, 
                NOFFERED_COUNT, NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE, 
                TABANDON_COUNT, TABANDON_EMIT_DATE, 
                OTHER_COUNT, OTHER_EMIT_DATE
      From      grid
      Where     PASS < 3  -- number of metrics to handle ( 3 )
   )

--    M a i n    S Q L : 
Select    ID, 
          Case When PASS = 1 Then 'NOFFERED_COUNT'
               When PASS = 2 Then 'TABANDON_COUNT'
               When PASS = 3 Then 'OTHER_COUNT'
          End  as METRIC_NAME,
          Case When PASS = 1 Then To_Char( NOFFERED_EMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )
               When PASS = 2 Then To_Char( TABANDON_EMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )
               When PASS = 3 Then To_Char( OTHER_EMIT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )
          End  as METRIC_EMIT_DATE,
          Case When PASS = 1 Then NOFFERED_COUNT
               When PASS = 2 Then TABANDON_COUNT
               When PASS = 3 Then OTHER_COUNT
          End  as METRIC_VALUE
From      grid

/*      R e s u l t : 
ID  METRIC_NAME      METRIC_EMIT_DATE      METRIC_VALUE
--  ---------------  --------------------  ------------
 5  NOFFERED_COUNT   2024-08-27 14:04:10              1
 5  TABANDON_COUNT   2024-08-27 14:06:15              1
 5  OTHER_COUNT      2024-08-27 14:23:45              1    */

See the fiddle here.
